# Check if 1 of 3 items are present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Panel where i display the Social Links of a User:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Follow me </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body profile_social_panel">
        <% if @user.facebook_link.present? %>
          <%= link_to image_tag('#'), @user.facebook_link %>
        <% end %>
        <% if @user.twitter_link.present? %>
          <%= link_to image_tag('#'), @user.twitter_link %>
        <% end %>
        <% if @user.youtube_link.present? %>
          <%= link_to image_tag('#'), @user.youtube_link %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I'm Searching for a method to check if `AT LEAST` one link is present so i can display the Panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OPTION 1**:

This can be accomplished directly on the view layer:

```
<% if @user.facebook_link.present? || @user.twitter_link.present? || @user.youtube_link.present? %>
```

**OPTION 2**:

*Alternatively*, this functionality can be abstracted into the model layer:

```
# app/models/user.rb
def link_present?
  if facebook_link.present? || twitter_link.present? || youtube_link.present?
    return true # Return true if true
  end
  false # Otherwise, return false
end
```

Then applied to the view:

```
# In your view
<% if @user.link_present? %>
```

Rails convention would dictate that this second approach is preferable, since it's more adherent to DRY principles.